# Scrapy spider converts float / int to string

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I always receive a string in my result, even in exported JSON.

Using double translate to replace everything. The `decimal_serializer` was just for testing purposes. I called `print(value)` inside and it returned a valid float value. In my result it's always unicode string. `add_value('offerCountNew', 1.3)` returns valid float value in my result.

I also tried removing any processor or serializer. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Item

```
offerCountNew = scrapy.Field(output_processor = TakeFirst(), serializer = decimal_serializer)
```

Spider

```
l.add_xpath('offerCountNew', 'number(translate(//*[@id="olp_feature_div"]//a[contains(@href, "new")], translate(//*[@id="olp_feature_div"]//a[contains(@href, "new")], "0123456789", ""), ""))')
```

Result

```
 'offerCountNew': u'1.0',
```

JSON

```
 "offerCountNew": "1.0",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def process_float_or_int(value):
    try:
        return eval(value)
    except:
        return value

offerCountNew = scrapy.Field(input_processor = MapCompose(lambda x: process_float_or_int(x)), output_processor = TakeFirst())
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working! Can you explain what you did and what caused the issue?

Comment: If the path is not found the default value is `False`, how to implement that case correctly so the value stays `False` instead of `nan`

Comment: input_processor gets called when item entered to the pipeline and mapcompose is simmilar to python map function. everytime when item comes to the pipeline map compose will run process_float_or_int function on each element. If you want to know more then refer to https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors